# JS compare the order of SOME elements in two different arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, string-comparison

I'm trying to figure out how to compare if certain elements in two arrays compare in the same order.

```js
var compare = function (arr1, arr2) {
//........
}

compare ([f,t,r,m], [s,f,t,r,q,p,m]); //should return true

compare ([f,t,r,m], [f,a,t,,m,r]); //should return false
```

I proceeded with a for loop and then identifying when the values match, then I'm pretty sure you should compare the arrays but I feel I'm missing something.

```js
var compare = function (a, b) {
  a.forEach(function(letter){
    for (i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
      if (letter===b[i]) {}
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: "*compare in the same order*" - what? Are you trying to determine whether one is a [*subsequence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of the other?

Comment: You need to be more clear about the question

Comment: @Bergi Yes, with the term subsequence it's easier to explain. My goal is the verify if arr1 is a subsequence of arr2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these functions will do this comparison with a `O(n)` runtime, where Ori Drori's solution runs in `O(n^2)`

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [0,1,4,3,9,10,2,5,6]; // 1,2,3 in wrong order
var c = [0,4,1,5,6,2,8,3,5];  // 1,2,3 in right order

// using foreach
function compare(a,b){
  var i = 0;
  b.forEach(function(el){
    if(el == a[i]) i++;
  })
  return i == a.length;
}

// using reduce
function compare2(a,b){
  return b.reduce(function(i, el){
    return el == a[i] ? i + 1 : i;
  }, 0) == a.length;
}

console.log(compare(a,b)  ==  false);  // should be false
console.log(compare(a,c)  ==  true);   // should be true
console.log(compare2(a,b) ==  false);  // should be false
console.log(compare2(a,c) ==  true);   // should be true
```

Comment: So actually your solution allowed me to solve the problem because OriDrori one didn't consider some exceptions, the test didn't specify which one. Here the link if you want to check it out http://www.codewars.com/kata/merged-string-checker/train/javascript

Answer (score 2):

Remove all letters from the 2nd array that don't appear in 1st array using [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Then iterate the result with [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), and check if every character appears in the same place in the 1st array:

```js
function compare(a, b) { 
  var arr = b.filter(function(c) { 
    return a.indexOf(c) !== -1; // use a hash object instead of indexOf if the arrays are large
  });
  
  return arr.every(function(c, i) {
    return c === a[i];
  });
}

console.log(compare(['f','t','r','m'], ['s','f','t','r','q','p','m'])); //should return true

console.log(compare(['f','t','r','m'], ['f','a','t','m','r'])); //should return false
```

Comment: This works in `O(n^2)` time while there are `O(n)` solutions

Comment: This is why I've add the comment `// use a hash object instead of indexOf if the arrays are large`. In small arrays it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an index for `array2` and check while iterating and return the comparison of the index and `array2` and the element of `array1`.

```js
function compare(array1, array2) {
    var i = 0;
    return array1.every(function (a) {
        while (i < array2.length && a !== array2[i]) {
            i++;
        }
        return a === array2[i++];
    });
}

console.log(compare(['f', 't', 'r', 'm'], ['s', 'f', 't', 'r', 'q', 'p', 'm'])); // true
console.log(compare(['f', 't', 'r', 'm'], ['f', 'a', 't', , 'm', 'r']));         // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
function compare(a,b){
    return b.filter(e => a.includes(e))
            .every((e,i) => e === a[i])
}

console.log(compare(["f","t","r","m"], ["s","f","t","r","q","p","m"]));

console.log(compare(["f","t","r","m"], ["f","a","t","m","r"]));
```